# Filtering Linux search to remove permission denied search results

Tags: linux, search

I have been searching (find . -name "file") on a Linux OS and want to filter out the many many lines in the search results that end in "permission denied". As the permission denied text is not part of the search string itself, I do not have a way of excluding it from the search output.
However removing it would make finding exactly what I want faster.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Evan

Answer (score 1):

You can simply redirect stderr output to /dev/null:

```
find . -name "file" 2>/dev/null
```

For further reading check  [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/)

Answer (score 0):

`find` writes its normal output to "standard output", while error messages like "permission denied" are written to "standard error". These are two different data streams. But they're normally both directed to your terminal, so their output ends up being intermixed.

The shell allows you to direct these data streams to different places. In your case, you could discard `find` error messages by sending them to `/dev/null`:

```
find . -name "file" 2>/dev/null
```

The "2" here means to direct file descriptor 2 (standard error) to /dev/null.

You can combine this with piping and redirection:

```
find . -name "file" 2>/dev/null | grep ....
find . -name "file" 2>/dev/null > list-of-files.txt
```

The first example passes the normal output of `find` to the `grep` command. The second writes the output of `find` to a file.